# Can't determine type for tag <cloudObjectStorage>

Tags: ibm-cloud

Context: cloud ibm com/developer/appservice/create-app

Hello,
I have first created an App based on defaultLanguage=ANDROID, navMode=starterkits, starterKit=f52aa8e3-d683-37e5-bae6-79c5e3140e9f

Next I created a service: Cloud Object Storage

Then I downloaded the zip.

I researched the text files in the zip.
In res/values/credentials.xml I found

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resources>
  <cloudObjectStorage>

My local Android Studio 4.0.1 refused to compile it.
Can't determine type for tag <cloudObjectStorage>

I guess the issue is that the IBM Android Template was defined for version 3.5.3 of the Studio. 
Any idea how to make the IBM code compatible with version 4.
```

Comment: Is your Gradle build failing? Can you update your Question with the complete error?

Comment: This is the complete error message. The error message indicates that the namespace of cloudObjectStorage is unknown.
And I have no glue what the correct namespace should be.

Comment: Did you create the project using `ibmcloud dev` CLI or App Development UI?

Comment: I used the web browser for creating the app, linked it with the Cloud Object Storage service and downloaded the zip.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and worked as expected

1. Created an Android app using `ibmcloud dev` interactive plugin
2. Added Cloud Object Storage service while creating the app
3. Imported the project to Android Studio 4.0.1
4. Updated the gradle plugin to the latest (6.1.1)

The gradle build succeeded without any errors[image]

Comment: Updating graddle to 6.1.1 did not solve the issue at my environment.
Can't determine type for tag '<cloudObjectStorage>